# Keras aggregated objective function

Tags: keras

How to add aggregated error to keras model?
Having table:

```
   g  x  y 
0  1  1  1   
1  1  2  2   
2  1  3  3   
3  2  1  2   
4  2  2  1
```

I would like to be able to minimize `sum((y - y_pred) ** 2)` error along with
`sum((sum(y) - sum(y_pred)) ** 2)` per group.
I'm fine to have bigger individual sample errors, but it is crucial for me to have right totals.

SciPy example:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
df = pd.DataFrame({'g': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 'x': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2], 'y': [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]})
g = df.groupby('g')
def linear(pars, fit=False):
    a, b = pars
    df['y_pred'] = a + b * df['x']
    if fit:
        sample_errors = sum((df['y'] - df['y_pred']) ** 2)
        group_errors = sum((g['y'].sum() - g['y_pred'].sum()) ** 2)
        total_error = sum(df['y'] - df['y_pred']) ** 2
        return sample_errors + group_errors + total_error
    else:
        return df['y_pred']

pars = differential_evolution(linear, [[0, 10]] * 2, args=[('fit', True)])['x']
print('SAMPLES:\n', df, '\nGROUPS:\n', g.sum(), '\nTOTALS:\n', df.sum())
```

Output:

```
SAMPLES:
   g  x  y  y_pred
0  1  1  1   1.232
1  1  2  2   1.947
2  1  3  3   2.662
3  2  1  2   1.232
4  2  2  1   1.947 
GROUPS:
   x  y  y_pred
g              
1  6  6   5.841
2  3  3   3.179 
TOTALS:
g        7.000
x        9.000
y        9.000
y_pred   9.020
```

Comment: In scipy documentation it says that `differential_evolution` does not use gradient methods (I don't know much about that method), but with keras your loss function you need something differentiable. How do you derive a "group by" sum? perhaps you need to try with a different model, maybe a RNN?

Comment: @JulioDanielReyes it is just example realization in SciPy. It works with every optimization method SciPy provides, but I want to use it in Keras. There is just simple Idea to minimize group total error instead of single errors.

Answer (score 3):

For grouping, as long as you keep the same groups throughout training, your loss function will not have problems about being not differentiable.

As a naive form of grouping, you can simply separate the batches.

I suggest a generator for that.

```
#suppose you have these three numpy arrays:
gTrain
xTrain
yTrain

#create this generator
def grouper(g,x,y):
    while True:
        for gr in range(1,g.max()+1):
            indices = g == gr
            yield (x[indices],y[indices])
```

For the loss function, you can make your own:

```
import keras.backend as K

def customLoss(yTrue,yPred):
    return K.sum(K.square(yTrue-yPred)) + K.sum(K.sum(yTrue) - K.sum(yPred))

model.compile(loss=customLoss, ....)
```

Just be careful with the second term if you have negative values.

Now you train using the method `fit_generator`:

```
model.fit_generator(grouper(gTrain,xTrain, yTrain), steps_per_epoch=gTrain.max(), epochs=...)
```

Comment: I included SciPy version of this task, but I am not sure how can I specify a variable to group by and how will it work with batches?

Comment: Keras works with "input data", "predicted=output data" and "true=target data". What is each in your example.

Comment: x - input data, y_pred - output data, y - target data (g is just a groups I care about. I want to sacrifice some individual samples accuracy to be able to predict accurate totals)

Comment: Keras is useful to make neural network models. What kind of network are you trying to create? Your question only talks about loss function.

Comment: Let’s say I’m trying to predict order value for each customer, but I know upfront that each week total sum will be 100. If we train regression it will minimize individual errors but total sums could be far from actual.

Comment: Updated the answer with a form of grouping.

Comment: This is just an idea, and I haven't test it, but tensorflow for instance have this function `tf.unsorted_segment_sum` that can be used with a more complex graph, that and the functional api of keras can get you somewhere https://keras.io/models/model/

Comment: @AlexOzerov, could you give some feedback on this new answer? I'm not sure why I'm still getting downvotes.

Comment: @DanielMöller I didn't have a chance to check it yet, but it does look like a potential solution to me. I think you will receive a bounty for this answer as no one has any solution at all. I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Ok :) - do you need any help in creating models or that's ok?