# Keras: Correct use of fit_generator, predict_generator, and evaluate_generator

Tags: python, keras, generator

I'm encountering weird behaviour when using `fit_generator`, `predict_generator`, and `evaluate_generator`, and I would like to ask the following questions, for which I could find no answer in the documentation:

1. Is it ok to have batches of different sizes when using `fit_generator`?

My batches are defined time-wise: they group the events that took place in the same hour. Each batch can therefore group a different number of events. For clarity, this is how my generators look like (following the logic in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647008/keras-aggregated-objective-function)):

```
def grouper(g,x,y):
     while True:
        for gr in g.unique():
            # this assigns indices to the entire set of values in g,
            # the subsects to all the rows in which g == gr
            indices = g == gr
            yield (x[indices],y[indices])

all_data_generator = grouper(df['batch_id'], X, Y)
train_generator = grouper(df.loc[df['set'] == 'train', 'batch_id'], X_train, Y_train)
validation_generator = grouper(df.loc[df['set'] == 'val', 'batch_id'], X_val, Y_val)
test_generator = grouper(df.loc[df['set'] == 'test', 'batch_id'], X_test, Y_test)
```

2. Is it ok to have different number of batches in `train_generator` and `validation_generator`?

For clarity, I pass those two (different) numbers explicitly to `fit_generator` in the call:

```
train_batches = df.loc[df['set'] == 'train', 'batch_id'].nunique()
val_batches = df.loc[df['set'] == 'val', 'batch_id'].nunique()

history = fmodel.fit_generator(train_generator, 
                             steps_per_epoch=train_batches, 
                             validation_data=validation_generator,
                             validation_steps=val_batches,
                             epochs=20, verbose = 0)
```

3. Predictions are wildly different depending on whether I use `predict_classes` or `predict_generator`, which baffles me.

Here's the code:

```
df['pred'] = fmodel.predict_classes(X)

# returns different results from
total_batches = df['batch_id'].nunique()
df['pred_gen'] = fmodel.predict_generator(all_data_generator, steps = total_batches)
```

4. Similarly, `evaluate` and `evaluate_generator` return different results.

The code:

```
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose = 0)

# returns different results from
scores_generator = fmodel.evaluate_generator(test_generator, steps=test_batches)
```

I know there are already many issues referring to my points 3. and 4. (e.g., [3477](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3477), [6499](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6499)) but the main takeaways there seem to refer to

- using ImageDataGenerator with/without rescaling;
- shuffling data, which according to [fit_generator documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) "Has no effect when steps_per_epoch is not None."
- using `workers > 1`, which by default is not the case.

So I'm wondering whether points 1. and 2. might be the culprits here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1 and 2

Yes, totally ok.
It's even expected that 2 be true.

## 3

Predict classes is not documented. What does it do exactly? I think it predicts indices while all other prediction methods predict the actual model's outputs, right?

## 4

This is sensible...

Are you pretty sure your generator is outputting exactly what you want?

You may try to see a few batches to compare them with `x` and `y`:

```
for i in range(aFewBatches):
    print(next(train_generator))
    #or create some comparisons
```

Even if the generators are correct, you are definitely reshuffling (actually sorting) your data, when you select your batches for the generator.

While `evaluate` will take the entire `x`, `y` data as it is, usually in batches of 32, `evaluate_generator` will take your selected batches. So, the metrics per batch will certainly vary, and the final result which is a mean of the batch metrics will also be different. So, unless the difference too big, it's ok.

PS: I'm not entirely sure whether `evaluate` will give you mean batch metrics or entire data metrics, but `evaluate_generator` will bring mean batch metrics, which is enough for a difference.

Comment: 3) it's actually a function from Keras 1.0
https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/1.0.0/models/sequential/
and although it's still compatible with Keras 2, I should perhaps not use it. Anyway, it's the same as using predict followed by np.argmax

Comment: 4) 
• Yes, I checked the output of my generators and they're returning what I'm expecting them to. Which also allows me to know that
• No, the batches are reshuffled by the generator, but always output in the same order.
• Indeed a small different shouldn't be worrying, but we're talking completely different predictions.